# Trigger a view before plugins are processed in Django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a views.py in my django-cms application. Is there any way to trigger a method in that views.py and add stuff to the context before any plugins are processed?

Comment: What exactly are you needing to do?

Comment: Well I want to query a web service and pass pieces of the response (which is in JSON) back to different plugins. I really want to know which is the best place to trigger that Query only once so that I can pass the different pieces to the plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hook the page(s) in question to a Django-CMS app hook. This will cause Django-CMS to retrieve the content for the page, but then hand over processing of the request to your view *before* the page is rendered. See http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/extending_cms/app_integration.html#app-hooks for more information.

This way you can add as many values to the context as you need before your plugins render, assuming you're using a custom plugin and you're overriding the `render()` method.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if you need more help. I've worked with Django-CMS quite a while.

Comment: Actually yes I could use some more help. My current issue is that I want the view in my "App-Hook to ONLY return the context and not render anything. Reason is I want the view to just process and add the data I need to the context and then the plugins will handle the rendering. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Are you using a custom plugin? or the built-ins?

Comment: I`m using custom plugins yes.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you might be better off using a context processor instead of hooking an app to a page. This would allow you to modify the context before the plugins are rendered.

Comment: From what I've found the context is triggered for every single plugin on the page. I would have to set a trigger somewhere to only execute the query once but that might be more light weight than having an App-Hook.